# calabash.framework not found when linking using -force_load

Tags: calabash

I am trying to link calabash.framework using Xcode 8 and calabash 0.20.3 but keep getting

`ld: file not found: project_dir/calabash.framework/calabash -lc++
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

I believe I have set the correct linker options and that my calabash.framework actually does exist at the path. I downloaded the calabash.framework using `calabash-iso download` in the project_dir. Checked the versions and its 0.20.3.

[Linker Flags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LaAfw.png)

[Calabash Framework](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYjOA.png)

Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you succeed with any progress on it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to move the `-lc++` to before the `--force_load`.